# How to "use" multiple modules with one "use"?

Tags: perl

I want use some packages and some pragmas in all my programs, like:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use My::ModuleA::Something;
use ModuleB qw(Func1 Func2);
```

I don't want repeat myself in every module, so looking for a way how to make one package e.g. `My::Common` what will contain the above packages and in my programs do only:

```
use My::Common;
say Func1("hello"); #say enabled and Func1 imported in the My::Common
```

how to achieve this?

The was read `preldoc -f use` and `perldoc perlmodlib` so i think I must "somewhat" to do this with BEGIN plus require&import, but absolutely don't know how.

---

**UPDATE:** I'm already tried the basic things.

With `require` - my prg.pl program.

```
require 'mymods.pl';
$var = "hello";
croak "$var\n";
```

mymods.pl contain

```
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Carp qw(carp croak cluck);
1;
```

DOES NOT WORKS. Got error:

```
$ perl prg.pl 
String found where operator expected at prg.pl line 3, near "croak "$var\n""
    (Do you need to predeclare croak?)
syntax error at prg.pl line 3, near "croak "$var\n""
Execution of prg.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

---

with "use My":

```
use My;
$var = "hello";
croak "$var\n";
```

my My.pm

```
package My;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Carp qw(carp croak cluck);
1;
```

DOES NOT WORKS either. Got the same error.

---

Any working idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd go with this:

```
package My::Common;
use 5.14.0;
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use Carp qw(carp croak cluck);

sub import {
    my $caller = caller;
    feature->import(':5.14');
    # feature->import('say');
    strict->import;
    warnings->import;
    ## autodie->import; # <-- Won't affect the caller side - see my edit.
    {
        no strict 'refs';
        for my $method (qw/carp croak cluck/) {
            *{"$caller\::$method"} = __PACKAGE__->can($method);
        }
    }
}

1;
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong, or there's a better way.

---

**EDIT**:

Sorry, I was wrong in using `autodie->import`...

This one should work, but it assumes that you always call `My::Common` from the `main` package:

```
package My::Common;
# ...
sub import {
    # ...
    strict->import;
    warnings->import;
    {
        package main;
        autodie->import;
    }
    # ...
}
```

So, of course, it's much safer and simpler to add a `use autodie;` to each script:

```
use My::Common;
use autodie;
# ...
```

Comment: YES! This works. ;) Thanx. So, need call import, and for the exported functions need do the dark VooDoo :) with *{"$caller....}.

Comment: @kobame: Oh wait, I just found out that `autodie->import` didn't work as I thought it would. Please take a look at my edit.

Comment: Why no mention of prior art on CPAN? [Toolkit](http://p3rl.org/Toolkit), [ToolSet](http://p3rl.org/ToolSet), [rig](http://p3rl.org/rig), [perl5i](http://p3rl.org/perl5i), [perl5](http://p3rl.org/perl5) do this already.

Comment: See [How can I export a list of modules with my own module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30814892/how-can-i-export-a-list-of-modules-with-my-own-module) for an overview of CPAN modules.

Answer (score 8):

It's actually fairly simple, if you override your "common" module's `import` method.  See the source of chromatic's [Modern::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Modern-Perl/) module for an example of exporting pragmas.

For re-exporting things defined in other modules, I seem to recall that `$export_to_level` (see the [Exporter](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Exporter) docs, although it's not explained all that clearly) should do that, although I can't find any good examples at the moment.  Another option would be [Pollute::persistent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Pollute::Persistent), although I haven't used it, don't know anyone else who's used it, and can't say how stable/solid it's likely to be.  If it works, though, it's probably the quickest and easiest option.

Answer (score 3):

I've just noticed a module called [rig](http://search.cpan.org/~rodrigo/rig-0.03/) in CPAN. Try it out.